# converting data in a text file in to a table in that text file itself

Tags: echo, sh

I used this script to obtain the data

```
#!/bin/sh
export DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`
export HOST=`hostname`
echo hostname is $HOST. > ${DATE}.txt
cut -f 1,3,5,6 -d : /etc/passwd  >> ${DATE}.txt
```

Output is

```
mom :1 : morris : /sbin
mini: 234 : mike : /usr/sbin
```

i am trying to convert this output in to table in .doc format

I didn't get help in any forums

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should tag this with the language (unless echo happens to be the name of a language I haven't heard of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to get this so it 'is' a MS windows .doc file, it just plain won't work (without a whole lot more code, and probably C language or perl, or ...?)

What you can do is set it up so the file can be imported into excel and then copy-pasted into a word table.

1 -- I'm not sure what your first line is supposed to accomplish, it doesn't appear in your output.

2 --  change your script to

script

```
 #!/bin/sh
 export DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`
 export HOST=`hostname`
 echo hostname is $HOST. > ${DATE}.xls
 awk -F: '{print $1,$3,$5,$6  }' /etc/passwd  >> ${DATE}.xls
```

3 -- Now the file should be a tab-delimted file that should auto-open in Excel. Copy-paste the active cells into your word document's table.

4 -- If you're a VB script person, you can write VB script to automate opening the xls file and moving to word. Else post a question here and tag it with appropriate VB tags.

I hope this helps.

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, and/or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer.

Comment: Thank You that works. but every thing is going as single line. can i get each variable to each block in excel sheet. with table headers name as the variable names. and also i dont know how to mark an answer as accepted in this forum.

Comment: do you mean one-really big line or one-line per line in /etc/passwd? If you're getting one-really-big line, then there is a problem. Asumming that is OK, the reason you are seeing one-line-per in Excel is that someplace you have already imported another type of data, probably CSV, and it has affected the settings. I only have Excel-2010 freebie here, so you need to find the menu option for import data into cells and change the field separator back to tab char. On older versions of Excel, it is the 2 or 3rd menu list on the menu bar from the right, and then about 1/2 down the list. Ask XcelUsrs

Comment: one line-per line in /etc/passwd  like this mom :1 : morris : /sbin is going in to one cell of excel sheet. Can mom go to one cell ,1 to adjacent cell,morris to next cell and /sbin in to next cell?

Comment: i.e $1 in to one cell, $3 in to adjacent cell, $5 in to next adjacent cell, $6 cell in to next cell. instead of entire line in to one cell.

Comment: Yes I understand your problem **except** that you keep showing ':' separating fields. Is that in the output file ${DATE}.xls? I'm assuming the file is tab-delimited after running the awk program, if not you have to fix that first. Most importantly, you have to fix how you are importing the data in Excel. Ask an Excel power user that you work with about the features I am talking about above. *I don't have access to Excel now and can't give you a definitive answer.* Sorry and good luck!

Comment: i will look for it. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F: '{print $1,$3,$5,$6  }' /etc/passwd  >> ${DATE}.csv
```

this will solve the problem